# Изменить визуально вывод кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть программный код, который проверяет, чтобы в строке были только числа, он выводит либо True либо False, но не понятно для какой переменной какое значение (если их много будет разных в списке), как сделать ,чтобы он выводил красиво, например s=False, a=True и так далее с разными переменными:

```
s="sf1sgsg"
a="12323"
q=[s,a]
for r in q:
    print(r.isdigit ())
```

Comment: Вижу проблему XY. Какова общая задача? Потому что пользователю кода, совершенно нет дела до имен переменных и пользователю эти имена все равно ничего не скажут. А программист сам знает, какие значения в какую переменную он записал. Если же эти значения приходя извне (что я подозреваю), то нужно выводит не имена переменных, а как раз источник, откуда пришли значения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно попробовать такой способ, но есть предположение, что так делать не надо:

```
def print_var():
    s="sf1sgsg"
    a="12323"
    q=[s,a]
    for name, value in locals().items():
        if value in q:
            print(f'{name} = {value.isdigit()}')

print_var()

>>> out
'''
s = False
a = True
```

Comment: Почему не надо ? Результат я хотел увидеть именно такой

Comment: @Роман при определенных обстоятельствах можно получить не вполне корректный результат, но в частных случаях может и нормально работать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать, например, вот так:

```py
s = 'sf1sgsg'
a = '12323'
q = [s, a]

for i in q:
    print(i, '=', i.isdigit())
```

Что я сделал:

1. Добавил отступ перед `for`.
2. Заменил `r` на `i` по правилам `PEP-8`.
3. В `print` прописал вывод значения `i`, `'='`, и `.isdigit`.
   Вывод:

```
sf1sgsg = False
12323 = True
```

Надеюсь, такой вариант подойдет.

Comment: а что именно pep8 говорит на эту тему?

Comment: Тоже не плохо, но в идеале я хотел именно сами переменные выводить, а не содержимое